# Can I create a read-only MS Word document in Python/ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, ms-word, plotly-dash

I need to create a read-only document in MS Word using Python.

I had a read through [python-docx library](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation, but I couldn't see a read-only config setting in their API.

I'm developing a [Plotly Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/) app so I'm open to other solution alternatives that might fit into this stack e.g. I see there is the ReactJS lib Redocx, but I also couldn't see if it has a read-only config option.